# Built js module is importing an object with default property instead of importing the default

Tags: javascript, node.js, next-auth

I'm creating a svelte-kit app with typescript, so it's internally using vite.

And I'm using next-auth's facebook provider (even though next-auth is for react, it's internal features can be jerry-rigged).

I'm importing the provider with `import FacebookProvider from 'next-auth/providers/facebook';`. This correctly imports the default function during development.

But when I actually build, I get `FacebookProvider is not a function` error. Debugging shows that `FacebookProvider` is now `{ default: [Function: Facebook] }`.

I've also tried `import * as FB from 'next-auth/providers/facebook';` and try to use `FB.default`. Same thing happened `FB.default` is now `{ default: [Function: Facebook] }` when I build, which is quite bizarre. There are 2 nested defaults now. Any idea what's happening here?

Since I'm using typescript, this seems like a problem with compiled output js files. My tsconfig is pretty barebone, mostly inheriting the defaults from svelte-kit.

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "paths": {
          "$lib": ["src/lib"],
          "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```

I've also looked at the source. `next-auth` is also using typescript and is just using `export default` as usual. I've also looked at the compiled js file. The way it's exporting is like so -

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.default = Facebook;
```

Is there some known problem with import that I'm missing? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this ? I have something similar when running tests with VueJs

Comment: @machinus Sadly, no. I ended up with a hacky code casting the whole thing to `any` and manually checking whether it's a function or object I think.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding the package to noExternals but only for the production build. Not sure why it does this though.